# WPF DatePicker LostFocus fires seven times

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, lost-focus

I have very simple scenario here. Look at layout, please:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>
    <DatePicker Grid.Row="1" 
                Name="_datePicker"
                LostFocus="_datePicker_OnLostFocus"></DatePicker>
</Grid>
```

and codebehind:

```
private void _datePicker_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("LostFocuse");
}
```

So, trouble is when I pick up some date and click `TextBox` then, event `LostFocus` fires 7 (**seven!**) times. One when `DatePicker`really lost focus when I ckicked on `TextBox` and remaining six times totally are not explainable for me.

How can I fix it? I need only **one** fireing of this event. Or may be I can use some other event? I tried `LostKeyBoardFocus` with the same result.

Comment: Did you look at your call stack to see where it is getting fired from?

Comment: @Krishna from somewhere in WPF system. I have nothing in my `Window`.

Comment: Can you tell us what you want to do on lostfocus event or why you chose this event? We can suggest an alternative if we know the context of your problem

Comment: @Krishna, I need any event that fires only one time when `DatePicker` lost its focus. I choose `LostFocus` event cause I thought it will give me that bahavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LostFocus is a routed event with route strategy set to **`Bubble`**. By bubble it means it will bubble up to its parent till root window until handled somewhere by explicitly setting **`e.Handled = true;`**.

So, that means even ***when child control lose focus it will bubble up to your datePicker that's why you see multiple hits to your method***.

You can check for property **`IsKeyboardFocusWithin`** which returns if focus is within your control. Since you are not interested in listening to child lost focus event, you can check for this property in your handler like this and execute your code only when actual focus is lost by datePicker:

```
private void _datePicker_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DatePicker picker = sender as DatePicker;
    if (!picker.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LostFocuse");
    }
}
```

Comment: it works, thx. But if this event is bouble, how do you think, why solution suggesed by `Sajeetharan` does't work properly? Setting `e.Handled = true;` must be stop bubbling up, is it? But actually, event keep on bubling and rises again and again.

Comment: That's because it's just not one child which is raising this event. In process multiple child controls raise the event like `CalendarButton` etc. You can check for `e.OriginalSource` to see what child control raised the event. `Sajetharan` solution is not right anyhow. He was setting `e.Handled = true` when it already reaches the datePicker parent control, it makes no change in the event raise. Event needs to be marked handled on child control.

Comment: hmmm... I dont't quite understand. I thought if we have bubling event and set `e.Handled = true;` in event handler, this must be cause of stopping bubling up. Handler invokes on all child controls as you said, `e.Handled = true;` will be set on first event rising, and it must will stop bubling. I am little confused about it.

Comment: @monstr - `I thought if we have bubling event and set e.Handled = true; in event handler, this must be cause of stopping bubling up.` - That's true but you need to handled it on child control but as per Sajeetharan code he is setting it to handled on handler attached on parent control which means it has already bubbled upto the parent now. To stop it to bubble up to parent you need to attach event on child control and mark it as handled there.

Comment: Got it, but it seems very strange and unexpected. Event handler invokes when event rises on `any` child control. But `e.Handled = true` can be set only in event handler that directly attched to parent control to have effect.
So, if I have no access to child control I cannot stop bubling process, until it will be completed on control that event handler attached to, is it? It will be nice to have possibility stop bubling process 
like that `if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(SomeChildControl) {e.Handled = true;}` - and bubling stops on control of `SomeChildControl` type.

Comment: You can attach handler to child controls from code behind by traversing Visual tree and attaching handler to each control. But I see no issue in bubbling up event since you can always filter out from OriginalSource which control actual raises an event.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a bool value to check for the first time and then set e.Handled to be true.

```
bool isFired = false;

private void _datePicker_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isFired)
        {
            isFired = true;
        }
        e.Handled = true;

}
```

Comment: It works, but this approach does't supress event fireing. Event actually fires 7 times too. Is there another way?

Comment: @monstr It will not fire 7 times, probably some part of your code causing this.

Comment: I posted all the code, I made blank window specially for testing. And I try to use your code in codebehind. Handler invokes six times (not seven, you are right :)). Code within `if(!isFired)` condition will be invoked once, but I enforced to use additional flag `isFired`. I don't like that approach as I already said.

Answer (score 1):

You have described the is the normal .NET behaviour of the [`UIElement.LostFocus` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx). From the linked page on MSDN:

> Occurs when this element loses logical focus.

Note that it says *logical* focus... WPF has two kinds of focus; logical and keyboard. Again from the linked page:

> Logical focus differs from keyboard focus if focus is deliberately forced away by using a method call but the previous keyboard focus exists in a different scope. In this scenario, keyboard focus remains where it is, and the element where a Focus method is called still gets logical focus.

Finally, why did the event get raised so many times? It is because even child elements within the `DatePicker` can remove the logical focus from it as they are clicked on and it can return to the `DatePicker` several times in quick succession as focus moves through the various internal controls. Once more, from the linked page:

> Because this event uses bubbling routing, the element that loses focus might be a child element instead of the element where the event handler is actually attached.

Comment: Thx for detailed exlanation, but as a result, what event of `DatePicker` I must use to have only one fireing by lost focus?

Comment: There is no such event.