# LostFocus Method Firing Multiple Times

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `MaskedTextBox` that I want to validate when the program loses focus on it. My method works how I want to aside from one problem, the event fires over and over again instead of just once (when the user enters an invalid date).

This is the method I am using;

```
private void onDateTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox _dateTexBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (!_dateTexBox.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(dateTextBox.Text.Substring(0, 2)) > 31)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid day.");
            dateTextBox.Focus();
        }

        if (Convert.ToInt32(dateTextBox.Text.Substring(3, 2)) > 12)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid month.");
            dateTextBox.Focus();
        }

        if (Convert.ToInt32(dateTextBox.Text.Substring(6, 4)) > 2100)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid year.");
            dateTextBox.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

I entered in the `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` check however the event still fires multiple times. How can I ensure that the event only fires once?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [WPF DatePicker LostFocus fires seven times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160459/wpf-datepicker-lostfocus-fires-seven-times)

> LostFocus is a routed event with route strategy set to Bubble. By
> bubble it means it will bubble upto its parent till root window until
> handled somewhere by explicitly setting e.Handled = true;.
>
> So, that means even when child control lose focus it will bubble up
> to your datePicker that's why you see multiple hits to your method.

Comment: Hi Mick thanks for your time. If I read that correctly then adding `e.Handled = true` into the `LostFocus` event won't stop the event from bubbling, and I already tried the method suggested in that answer (`IsKeyboardFocusWithin`).  Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I wonder Mick, is it worth deleting this answer, and closing the above question as a duplicate of the linked question? Do you think they are reasonably close duplicates?